# Can I slide an android viewpager within a different time slot?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I want to slide my an android viewpager within a different slide slot.It means first page comes after the 5 second and second page will be appearing in 8 second.I need to slide viewpager but that slides are need to come within different time frame.is it possible to do that thing? Any help to slow this error would be highly appreciated.

I did the following code segment.But it will change viwepager for some constant time period.

```
 final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (currentPage == signageResourceStoreModelList.size()) {
                currentPage = 0;
            }
            try {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage, true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            currentPage = currentPage + 1;
        }
    };

    timer = new Timer();

    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() { // task to be scheduled
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(Update);
        }
    }, DELAY_MS, PERIOD_MS);
}
```

Comment: Better if you provide some code you've already tried.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, definitely you can do this by some programming logic.

Declare a class variable 
for eg. `int time=2000;`

To change the view inside viewpager programmatically

```
public void MoveNext(View view) {
    pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
    //Write logic of incrementing time here
    //e.g.time=time+1000;

}
```

Now define a handler

```
  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        MoveNext();
      }
    },time);
```